# How to make animation play indefinitely

Tags: android, animation

I am using NineOldAndroid's AnimatorSet and ObjectAnimator objects to animate some view

i want the animation to play indefinitely, how can I make that happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the docs [here](http://nineoldandroids.com/#usage):

```
ValueAnimator colorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this, "backgroundColor", /*Red*/0xFFFF8080, /*Blue*/0xFF8080FF);
colorAnim.setDuration(3000);
colorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
colorAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
colorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
colorAnim.start();
```

Comment: I need to use the AnimatorSet not the ValueAnimator - how do i achieve what i need with the AnimatorSet ?

Comment: I didn't realize that my given object was indeed a value animator, this helped, thanks!

Comment: Haha sorry for not getting back to you. Glad it worked out, after a month ;)